# Overriding odoo 11 javascript private method

Tags: javascript, odoo-11

I have a situation where I need to take a specific action when a row is clicked in a tree view for a given model. The problem is with the rewriting of the Odoo JS framework in V11, the method I am interested in is declared private. Here the method I want to override from the `list_renderer.js` file.

```
/**
 * @private
 * @param {MouseEvent} event
 */
_onRowClicked: function (event) {
    // The special_click property explicitely allow events to bubble all
    // the way up to bootstrap's level rather than being stopped earlier.
    if (!$(event.target).prop('special_click')) {
        var id = $(event.currentTarget).data('id');
        if (id) {
            this.trigger_up('open_record', {id:id, target: event.target});
        }
    }
},
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
/**
 * @private
 * @param {MouseEvent} event
 */
_onRowClicked: function (event) {
    //The condition may be something else
    if (this.model=='my_module.my_model'){  
        // Do a specific action here
    }
    else{
        this._super(event);
    }
},
```

I have tried following, but the `console.log('Test')` output is never displayed

```
var ListRenderer = require('web.ListRenderer');

ListRenderer.include({
    _onRowClicked: function (event) {
        console.log('Test');
    },
})
```

Any idea on how I can achieve this? 
Thanks in advance!!